# Call self in object construction

Tags: c#

I am initializing an object with several properties. However, there are multiple properties that are always the same (styling).

Consider the following initializing block of code:

```
private static Button _saveButton = new Button
{
    Text = "Save",
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    WidthRequest = 500,
    IsVisible = false
    //applyStandard(this) ?
};
```

I would like to pass `_saveButton` to a method, which changes its `TextColor` and `BorderColor` property with something like `void applyStandard(View v)`.

How could I do that, if possible?

Comment: Create a static method in the Button class that does what you need?

Comment: Create a subtype; or create a method that returns a new button.

Comment: You can't do that in an object initialiser.

Comment: @Logard But I would like to use the method within the initializing brackets.

Comment: Why? Creating a CreateButton method which initializes and then modifies your Button seems like it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the button instance in the initializer, but you can make an extension method that you call right after it:

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static Button ApplyStandard(this Button button) {
        button.TextColor = Colors.Red;
        return button;
    }

}
```

By returning the button from the extension method, you can chain it into the creation:

```
private static Button _saveButton = new Button {
  Text = "Save",
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
  WidthRequest = 500,
  IsVisible = false
}.ApplyStandard();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the in the object initializer. You need to separate the method call from initialization.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm guessing 1-this was already said in comments and 2-it doesn't give an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is nearly there, i think youre approaching the problem from the wrong direction. As already mentioned, you cant do what youre proposing with object initialization syntax. The simplest way to solve your problem (without simply creating your own button type) would be to have a method that creates a button, and sets all of your common properties. You can then set any of the others on a per instance basis:

```
private static Button CreateCustomButton()
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    // set other properties, initial setup etc...

    return button;
}
```